# Creating a list that never repeats random number

Tags: python

I have my program functioning properly, but, I want the answer list to never have a duplicated number, and also always have 4 numbers. I have tried using the function

```
num_digits = 4

answer = []
for i in range(num_digits):
    r = random.randint(0,9)
    if r not in answer: answer.append(r)
```

but this returns three or even two numbers sometimes. I need 4 numbers in the list each time.
My current code looks like this

```
def game(number_of_digits):
    answer = [random.randint(0,9) for n in range(number_of_digits)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: How about your for loop iterating until the length of answer is `num_digits’?

Comment: What about `random.sample(range(0,9), 4)`

Comment: Either of the above, though @barry probably should have said a while loop not for, that is while (answer length < 4)

Comment: I like both ideas. I think I will keep the for loop for now. Try the random.sample

Comment: Thanks a lot. JvdV worked like a charm. Really appreciate it!